# ElasticBeanstalk suddenly starts failing to deploy Django App with "Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed" exception

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using elastic beanstalk to deploy my Django application. Today it suddenly stopped working without any breaking changes from the application side (I've changed some templates, nothing more).

The deployment time outs after 10 minutes of trying to deploy the app and nothing happens.

The only more or less useful hints I can see in the log is this:

```
[2020-02-20T15:00:20.437Z] INFO  [19057] - [Application update .../postbuild_0_myproject/Command 01_migrate] : Activity execution failed, because: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

  ERRORS:
  education.Author.photo: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
  HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "pip install Pillow".
  education.Course.cover_image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
  HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "pip install Pillow".
  education.CourseCategory.icon_image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
  HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "pip install Pillow".
  Using staging settings
  App receivers connected
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)


[2020-02-20T15:00:20.437Z] INFO  [19057] - [Application update .../postbuild_0_myproject/Command 01_migrate] : Activity failed.
[2020-02-20T15:00:20.437Z] INFO  [19057] - [Application update .../postbuild_0_myproject] : Activity failed.
[2020-02-20T15:00:20.437Z] INFO  [19057] - [Application update ...] : Activity failed.
[2020-02-20T15:00:20.507Z] INFO  [19057] - [Application update app-9a24-200220_145942-stage-200220_145942@142/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Activity failed.
[2020-02-20T15:00:20.507Z] INFO  [19057] - [Application update app-9a24-200220_145942-stage-200220_145942@142/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2020-02-20T15:00:20.508Z] INFO  [19057] - [Application update app-9a24-200220_145942-stage-200220_145942@142] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
```

But I already have Pillow in `requirements.txt` and the log above says:

```
  Requirement already satisfied: Pillow==6.2.1 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 51))
```

**How can I troubleshoot and fix this? And how can I avoid similar issues in the future? I am really frightened that the same problem may randomly pop out on production environment.**

---

Here's some more info about the configuration:

Here's what I have in `.ebextensions`:

`01_packages.config`:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
```

`db-migrate.config`

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: myproject.settings
```

`django.config`

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: myproject/wsgi.py
```

`wsgi_custom.config`

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgihacks.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two Elastic Beanstalk environments with the same issue (one web tier env and a worker env).

On one of them the issue was resolved by restarting the environment.

The other one failed to restart and timed out every time on any operation. This one I managed to fix by going to configuration > capacity and changing the minimum and maximum number of instances to 0. I've applied the changes, waited for them to apply and then returned the previous values for min and max instance numbers.

That fixed the issue.

I still have no idea what caused the issue in the first place and would love to receive some comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a pain and a known issue with Django when using the `ImageField` model/form. Due to Pythons dynamic import system it will suddenly appear and annoyed the hell out of me when I first came across it.

The way I normally fix this is by using [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) and its equivalent of a virtualenv to ensure the right interpreter (the one with my packages) is used.

If you are not using a virtualenv or equivalent, set one up now, if you are already using one then check you are installing pillow with `pip3 install pillow` - the `pip3` being important here as on debian (and many other) systems normal `pip` will only install for python 2.x.

Using conda will ensure this doesnt happen in production, but I would also add it to your checklist of things to test when deploying - check correct version of pillow setup and working.

Comment: Well, elastic beanstalk does that automatically, the package is installed. When running pip3 install for it it says that requirement is satisfied. How exactly conda could help?

Comment: conda just has a better container system, you can _only_ install packages for your version of python and there is no chance of typing `pip` instead of `pip3` (just `conda install x`). It definitely sounds like the wrong interpreter is being used in this case, is the virtualenv activated when installing the package _and_ when running the server?

Comment: Gotcha. Well, no, the container does not have any other interpreters installed, although I understand what you are getting at.

Comment: Anyway, managed to resolve the issue, although I have no idea what caused the problem

Comment: I agree its weird, so no system wide interpreter just the one in the virtualenv? Huh

Comment: Well, yeah, there is a system-wide interpreter, but I don't have any control on whichever one elastic beanstalk uses when deploying and running tasks